# how to stop background-color covering whole screen

Tags: html, css, background-color

I don't want my background colour to cover the whole length of my screen. how do i do this?

```
<body>

<h1 style = "color:blue;text-align:center;background-color:green;">text</h1>

</body>
```

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHH4x.png)

Comment: Well what width do you want it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You need to decide how much of your screen should be green, and then get the HTML to reflect this by setting the width and/or height of the relevant element. What you have provided will always default to extending across and down the screen.

Comment: As you are getting into HTML and CSS you will find it helpful to know which elements are `block`-level as well as the various types of `display` values in CSS. See the following link as well as the 'SEE ALSO' section at the bottom: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a span and apply your style to it.

```html
<body>

<h1 style = "color:blue;text-align:center;">

<span style="background-color:green;">text</span>
</h1>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`h1` is a block element, You can add `display:inline-block` ,If you want it to be cetnred you can wrap it in a div with `text-align:center;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<body >
<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1 style = "color:blue;background-color:green;display:inline-block">text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this stops me from centering the writing. is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap text into span and apply background color for that span

Comment: this also seems to stop me from centring the text. is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `h1` is a block level element and the most of browsers set a 100 percent width for block level elements. You should use `flex` CSS to fix this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.head-tag {
  color:blue;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="head-tag">text</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the h1 in a div and set the width of that div.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes wrapping the content is not an option (e.g. for text editor components with iframe inside), so you can try this workaround:

```
body {
  background: #f00;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f00 100%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```